# Using Date VBA Function, but need to add four hours on to it before formatting it.

Tags: vba, excel

I'm accessing a file that name changes based on of the date of UTC. I'm on USE. So using the Date VBA function, sometimes it won't grab the file because its the next day on UTC, and I'm on USE.

```
Dim dttDate As Date
dttDate = Date

Set LMData = Workbooks.Open("C:\...\PRIVATENAME" & Format(dttDate, "yyyy-mm-dd") & ".csv")
```

I've considered Now + 4 (because now deals in time as well), but the issue is I seen on VBA that single integers are read as months and I cannot determine how to read it as hours. In excel functions dates are # values so + 4 would add 4 hours to it.

Comment: You can access UTC time directly via the Windows API.  See Chip Pearson's [Time Zones And Daylight Savings Time](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/TimeZoneAndDaylightTime.aspx) for an elegant way of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reference: [Date and Time Functions in VBA](http://www.classanytime.com/mis333k/sjdatetime.html)

> Time represents the decimal part of the double that Access stores for
>   date and time. Since adding 1 to a stored date/time represents 1 day
>   or 24 hours, each hour is stored as .041666, or 1/24 of a day. In
>   Access all times are stored as a fraction of a day. Each hour is 1/24
>   of a day, each minute 1/1440, each second 1/86400. So 3:00 is stored
>   as .125 (or 1/8 of a day), and 16:00 is stored as 0.666, (or 2/3 of a
>   day). Conversely, 0.2 represents 4:48 hours (1/5 of a day), and so on.

```
dttDate = int(Now + 4/24)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation as well!